# What is the best approach for multi categories filtering

Tags: craft3, categories, routes

I need a solution for a good filter approach in Craft.

I used 3 Categories related to an entry (Project). The 3 Categories are
(Type / State / Location)
How do I have to set up the routes for the multiple slugs?

Example:

```
example.com/project/office/finished/germany.
```

I already fetch projects with AJAX for one category, but it should also work with a combination of categories.

Answer (score 2):

You could leave the *Category URI Format* blank in your settings and [set an advanced route](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/routing.html#advanced-routing-with-url-rules) in `config/routes.php` like so:

```
'projects/<type:{slug}>/<state:{slug}>/<location:{slug}>' => ['template' => 'projects/index'],
```

Which would make `{{ type }}`, `{{ state }}` and `{{ location }}` available as variables in your template.